# How to prove a path made up from minimal paths at each vertex is also minimal?

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

> Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ with positive weights $w(e)>0$ for any edge $e\in E$. The starting node is $s$. For every node $v$ there is a path $P_{s,v}$ from $s$ to $v$. An edge $e=(u,v)\in E$ will be called **useful** if it's the last edge in some minimal path $P_{s,v}$.
>
> Prove that if all the edges of $P_{s,v}$ are useful then $P_{s,v}$ is a minimal distance path.

It seems that the proof is trivial but I'm not sure:

Let $l(P_{s,a})$ be the length of a path.

For $l(P_{s,a})=1$ the proof is trivial. Suppose that $l(P_{s,b})=k$ is a minimal distance path then we'll prove that $l(P_{s,c})=k+1$ is still a minimal distance path.

We know that $P_{s,b}$ is a minimal distance path from $s$ to $b$. $P_{s,c}=P_{s,b}+e_c$ where $e=(b,c)$ is a new edge. It is given that $e_c$ is a useful edge that is it is the last edge in the minimal distance path from $s$ to $c\quad(*)$ .

$P_{s,b}$ is a minimal distance path by induction assumption and because of $(*)\implies$ $P_{s,c}$ is also a minimal distance path. If we repeat the process for all edges $e_{k+2},...,e_v$ in $P_{s,v}$ where $e_v$ is the last edge in $P_{s,v}$ then $P_{s,v}$ is a minimal distance path.

Comment: To be clear, **useful** is a word used only with respect to a starting vertex? In this case that vertex is $s$? So maybe the phrase could be **useful for $s$**?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yes **useful** is used in the context of the starting node $s$.

Comment: I think your logic is correct, but the critical step in the last paragraph is not very well explained. Basically, $P_{s,b}$  is minimal from s to b. Also, there is a minimal path from s to c that contains e. Thus, that path is of the form $P'_{s,b}+e$ (it goes through b and then over e). Now, this means that $P'_{s,b}$ must be a minimal path from s to b. Thus, $P_{s,b}$ and $P'_{s,b}$ are both minimal, so are of the same length. Thus, the path in question $P_{s,b}+e$ is of the same length as (we know minimal) path $P'_{s,b}+e$, so is itself minimal, Q.E.D.